# batch filter (r.mfilter) raster time series, keep original file name

Tags: qgis, batch, filter

I want to apply a filter (r.mfilter) to a raster time series while keeping the original filenames. For a similar problem when batch converting file formats in QGIS, I entered : - as file name when selecting save directory, and then "autofill with parameter values". This worked in another function, but not with batch processing in r.mfilter.